# Vector image with fixed line width

Tags: vector, stroke, zoom

I would like to create/export a vector image with fixed line widths, independent of the zoom level. 
I've already found the possibility to use `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` in an SVG image, which makes the line width independent of my transformations.
But that is not what I want. I need to create an image file that I can send to someone else, while he/she can open it in web/pdf/image browser, zoom in, while keeping the line width fixed.

Example: I have this image:

[image]

What I want after enlarging it 10 times in browser/pdf viewer:

[image]

What I got instead:

[image]

I'm struggling with this for quite long, so I wonder, is it even possible? I understand that with raster images, this is impossible in principle, but isn't there a way to achieve this with vector images?

Comment: I think you might be able to do this using CSS to modify the stroke width. I found this [Stroke-Width (CSS Tricks)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-width/) if it's any help.

Comment: In SVG this should be possible depending on how and where you display the file, but in PDF I *think* it's impossible. Objects in a PDF must have physical dimensions and can't be responsive. How should strokes like this print?

Comment: `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` is the way to go here. But it can only work with SVGs that are rendered using a viewer that understands and renders vectors, which isn't possible using a PDF or other similar formats that force pre-rendered sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this. Using the information from comments and @joojaa answer, I concluded that PDF is not an option. I focussed on SVG, and I was able to achieve the result using the embedded CSS block with `stroke-width` property. However, this is not enough to achieve the wanted behavior in the browser.

**The key is to set the stroke width in viewport units.** Example:

```
<svg xmlns...">
    <style>
        path { stroke-width: 0.1vw; }
    </style>
    ...
```

This solution works for Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. It does not work for IE (it ignores the embedded style), but I guess it is a question for a different community.

Answer (score 1):

PDF specification has no such capability. PDF is a print preparation/archival/wysiwyg format. Its simply not meant for this usecase.

Like others have said svg files in a browser have this property. But thats not a universal works in all svg rendererers kind of thing. Browsers are especially flexible, so you could even make it thinner when you zoom in if you wanted to.